# IndexedDB.open returns null on Safari iOS 8.1.1 and halts execution on Cordova. Even worst on iOS 8.1.2

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, safari, indexeddb

I know that IndexedDB implementation in iOS is quite buggy, like the shared ids between different tables. However it is not working at all for me. I am trying to develop a Cordova app for iOS that should use IndexedDB, so I created the following code:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

var request = window.indexedDB.open("mydata");  //also tried open("mydata", 1) with same result
console.log('OPEN DB')
request.onupgradeneeded = function() {...};
request.onsuccess = function() {...};
```

When running this snippet in the Cordova app, the `OPEN DB` print is not shown, the execution gets stuck at the `indexedDB.open` call (no error log or anything at all). I thought this may be a Cordova issue so I decided to run the same code in plain Safari browser although it should be the same as Cordova is just using a UIWebview that, to my understanding, should be using the same webkit version as the browser.

When running in Safari `iOS 8.1.1` the `OPEN DB` log is printed but it crashes on the next line due to `request` variable being `null`. When running on `iOS 8.1.2` it crashes on the `open()` call showing  a log saying:

> SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent

What the $@#%! is going on? I see some people complaining about buggy behaviour but I can't even open the DB, is this normal or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sadly indexedDB isn't supported by the UIWebView

http://www.sencha.com/blog/apple-shows-love-for-html5-with-ios-8

- > IndexedDB was added to iOS 8 Safari and “WKWebView”
- > IndexedDB is not available in iOS 8 “UIWebView” or Home screen apps

But you can try with the WKWebView cordova plugin
http://devgirl.org/2014/11/10/boost-your-ios-8-mobile-app-performance-with-wkwebview/

Comment: Thanks for the WKWebView info. Sadly, when using the cordova plugin and try to open the DB it triggers the onerror callback with a nicely empty error object so I have no idea on what is going on.